# How to adopt styles of one styled-components component to another?

Tags: styled-components

Given the following code:

```js
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Link = () => /* ... */;
const PrimaryLink = styled(Link)`
  color: #666;
`;
const ExternalLink = styled.a /* How to extend with PrimaryLink, but keeping styled.a */;
```

I want `ExternalLink` component (which is `styled.a`) to extend styles from `PrimaryLink` component. How do I do it?

I have attempted:

```js
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Link = () => /* ... */;
const PrimaryLink = styled(Link)`
  color: #666;
`;
const ExternalLink = styled.a`${PrimaryLink}`;
```

but that produces empty styles.

The only way I can think of to make this work is by adding a third variable ``` css`` ``` that would extend both components, e.g.

```js
import styled, {css} from 'styled-components';

const BaseLinkStyle = css`
  color: #666;
`;
const Link = () => /* ... */;
const PrimaryLink = styled(Link)`${BaseLinkStyle}`;
const ExternalLink = styled.a`${PrimaryLink}`;
```

Answer (score 2):

I tend to do what you suggest, i.e. using a style function:

```
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components';

const baseStyle = css`
  ...
`;

const Link = () => { ... };

const PrimaryLink = styled(Link)`
  ${baseStyle}
  ...
`;

const ExternalLink = styled.a`
  ${baseStyle}
  ...
`;
```

I think this would also work:

https://styled-components.com/docs/api#as-polymorphic-prop

https://styled-components.com/docs/api#attrs

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Link = () => { ... };

const PrimaryLink = styled(Link)`
  ${baseStyle}
  ...
`;

const ExternalLink = styled(PrimaryLink).attrs({ as: 'a' })`
  ...
`;
```